# Question on limit of integral

Tags: measure-theory

I am considering a finite measure space $(X, \mathcal{A},\mu)$ ,i.e. $\mu(X)< \infty$. Let $(u_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty} \in \mathcal{L}^{1}(\mu)$ be a sequence which satisfies:

a) $u_{n} \to 0$ (pointwise) for $n \to \infty$

b) $\vert u_{n}(x)  \vert \leq 1$ for all $x \in X$ and all $n \geq1$

I am asked to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{X}u_{n} d\mu = 0$.

**My attempt:**

I initially wanted to use the Lebesgue dominated convergence but $w(x)=1$ is causing me problems. The theorem requires that $w(x)=1 \in \mathcal{L}^{1}(\mu)$. This seems impossible

Could someone guide in the right direction?

Comment: Your dominating function $w(x)=1$ indeed lies in $\mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ because $\mu(X) < \infty$. Note that $$ \int_{X}w(x)\,\mu(\mathrm{d}x)=\mu(X)<\infty.$$

Comment: Yes, you are right. I missed that. Appreciate the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your  idea we Dominated Convergence is correct.

Note that $X$ has finite measure so  $\int_X 1d \mu =\mu(X)<\infty$

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I got it. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't used that $\mu(X)<\infty$. Why does this make your argument work?

Comment: You are right. It makes the argument work since: $\int w(x)d\mu = \int1d\mu=\mu(X) < \infty$. The last equality holds since the measure space is finite.